# Electrical impedance

Tags: electrical-resistance, oscillators, vibrations

I really just wanted to confirm if my understanding about electrical impedance in an AC circuit is correct.

So essentially the equation of impedance that $(\text{mod }Z)^2 = R^2 + (\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C})^2$ means that at $\omega_0$, the natural frequency or at resonance, $(\text{mod }Z)^2$ is minimized, hence implying that the current is maximized due to $V=IZ$. So does this mean that even though the rate of flow of charge is maximized (current) the amplitude of the charge isn't actually maximized because of the amplitude curve and the fact that max amplitude doesn't occur at $\omega =\omega_0$ when there is damping (resistance, $R$,  in this case). And we can understand this intuitively by the fact that increasing current means more charge flows but there are also more collisions and so there will become a point after which the resistance is too high and the charge actually decreases, even if current increases ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “amplitude of the charge”.  In circuits we usually only measure voltage and current. Also what is $\omega_0$?

Comment: I am talking about forced oscillations and the amplitude graph you get where it peaks close to resonance because this is a forced AC driven circuit. In this case w0 is equal to sqrt (1/LC)

Comment: you did not answer what you consider the amplitude of charge.

Comment: "amplitude of charge" -- That is meaningless in standard circuit jargon.

Comment: Hi, so when we have a mechanical forced oscillator the amplitude response function measures how large x, which is the displacement,  at different frequencies. So when we moved onto LC circuits, RLC circuits and AC driven circuits, we were told q is the electrical equivalent to x . I am not too great on electricity and so I am not too sure what the answer to your comments are but I've added a picture of the notes to try and show you what i mean. A(w) is the amplitude response function.

Comment: The amplitude of the charge would be the maximum of the oscillating charge which occurs on the capacitor.

Comment: Keep in mind that the equation for the voltage drops around a driven AC circuit can be put into a form which resembles an equation for the sum of the x components of three vectors, which are rotating in a 2D plane, to get the x component of the resultant vector.  To keep track of the relative phases, it is convenient to refer to these (non-existent) vectors when doing calculations. The vectors can be visualized in an xy plane or in the complex number plane, but either way only one component of the  vectors has physical significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum charge on the capacitor depends on the current and the frequency.  If the frequency goes up, the current will have less time on each cycle to charge the capacitor. This suggests the the maximum charge may occur at a frequency less than the resonant frequency. (The rate of change of the current is small near the peak of the resonance curve.)  To find the frequency for maximum charge, solve rhe voltage equation  for the charge as a function of frequency, and take the derivative to maximize that.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your answer. Am I right in saying that if R =0  then the maximum of the amplitude curve occurs at $\omega =\omega_0$ but this is a larger frequency than what it would be if there was a resistance, but the reason a larger frequency gives a larger amplitude in this case is because the current, I, tends to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

According to the added picture, the AC source has a frequency different from $\omega_0$. That is why the formula for $A(\omega)$ depends on $L$ and $C$.

Note that if $\omega = \omega_0$:$$A(\omega) = \frac{\frac{V_0}{L}}{\sqrt{\gamma^2\omega^2}} = \frac{V_0}{\omega R}$$

Differentiating q with respect to time we get the current, and its amplitude in this case ($\omega = \omega_0)$ is only function of the source and the ohmic resistance $R$:

$I = \omega \frac{V_0}{\omega R} e^{i(\omega t - \delta)} = \frac{V_0}{R}e^{i(\omega t - \delta)}$